# Add fixed argument to command arguments in docker entrypoint

Tags: linux, bash, docker, terminal

I want to add a fixed parameter to a command in a docker entrypoint s.t. the command is executed like so:

`command user_arg1 fixed_arg user_arg2`

Using a linux terminal as an example, instead of running:

`echo arg1 arg2`

I want to run:

`<some set of commands> arg1 arg2`

such that the final command that's run is:

`echo arg1 fixed_arg arg2`

Is there a way to use basic command line tools to achieve this instead of writing a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the fixed argument in the middle of the command, you have to use a script.  You don't need bash extensions, though, and you can make this work even with the basic POSIX shell in BusyBox or Alpine Linux.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
first="$1" # save the first option
shift      # remove it from the options list
           # now $@ is all the options except the first one
exec the_command "$first" some_arg "$@"
```

In the context of a Docker entrypoint, it will get pass the entire `CMD` (or `docker run` command part or Compose `command:`) as options, so you could make this conditional on what the command actually is.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
  the_command)
    first="$2"
    shift 2
    exec the_command "$first" some_arg "$@"
    ;;
  *)
    exec "$@"
    ;;
esac
```

The only thing Docker will do natively is [combine the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact); there's no way to rearrange the options or otherwise manipulate them.  A pattern I find useful is for the `CMD` to be the actual command you want to run, and the `ENTRYPOINT` to be a script that eventually runs it.  That can manipulate the command string however you want, including choosing to completely ignore it or change the actual command that gets run.

Answer (score -1):

The `RUN` command in a dockerfile should work, an example is,

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'source $HOME/.bashrc; \
echo $HOME'
```

More information in the docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run